# Mapbox NavigationView GPS tracking arrow drawable

Tags: android, mapbox

I need to change the default arrow with circle in the navigation route view. I tried the following and it is not working.

```
 <style name="NavigationLayerStyle">
        <item name="mapbox_gpsDrawable">@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp</item>

    </style>


<com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:navigationViewMapStyle="@style/CustomNavigationViewDark"
    app:navigationDarkTheme="@style/CustomNavigationViewDark"
    app:navigationLightTheme="@style/CustomNavigationViewDark"
    app:navigationViewPrimary="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationViewLocationLayerStyle="@style/NavigationLayerStyle"/>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: @Jlthin do you have solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to and i figured out in few hours
First, you need to declare the custom style with your custom drawable.

In order to do this, you need to declare the "NavigationLocationLayerStyle" style extension (which contains the drawable) and give to him the attribute "mapbox_gpsDrawable"

```
<style name="customGPS" parent="NavigationLocationLayerStyle">
    <item name="mapbox_gpsDrawable">@drawable/bike_icon_map</item>
</style>
```

Then, declare the "main theme" with your custom location layer style

```
<style name="customdark" parent="NavigationViewDark">
    <item name="navigationViewLocationLayerStyle">@style/customGPS</item>
</style>
```

Once done, you simply have to inject your theme to your navigation view
To achieve this, you can't use any method of navigationView, because they all don't work (or at least i didn't find the correct one). So i wrote just this command (in kotlin):

```
(this as Context).setTheme(R.style.customdark)
```

This roughly works, hope is not too late.